# Displaying typed characters on new line

Tags: c#

May be funny question, I am very newbie in C#

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       int a;
       a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
       Console.WriteLine(a);
       Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
```

I expected that after typing any character, these character would be written on new line in console, though these are printed on one line. where I am wrong?

P.S.

```
Console.WriteLine("ASD");
Console.WriteLine("DSA");
```

this displayed as expected:

```
ASD
DSA
```

Comment: "Any character" won't work because you're converting to an `int`, however, if you input an `int` into this program, for example 5, it does print the value onto a new line as you would expect.

Comment: @Scott "Any character" works and I can write any alphabetic character at least (Why works, I dont know). when trying input only `int` characters, they printed at one line, anyway

Comment: So if you input a `string` value using that code it doesn't throw a `FormatException`?

Comment: No, I dont get any exception, warning or error, when I input a `string` value using that code. this `string` value just printed in console successfully

Answer (score 3):

Every call of the Console.WriteLine() method prints a new line.
What your example does is take all the input and print that input a single time.

You could try this instead:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a;

        while(true)
        {
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: included version that uses char and Console.Read() as that seems to be more appropriate

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char a;

        while(true)
        {
            a = (char)Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant.
Did you mean that when given an input string of "123", you expect an output of:
1
2
3
?

Because the Console.ReadLine() command evaluates the entire input string.

You could try outputting the input into a char and printing that.

Perhaps this is more what you want? (excuse me for the formatting)


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char a;

            while(true)
            {
                a = (char)Console.Read();
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadLine()` method does not terminate the line (as you would probably expect). A quote From MSDN :

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage
>   return (hexadecimal 0x000d), a line feed (hexadecimal 0x000a), or the
>   value of the Environment.NewLine property. The returned string does
>   not contain the terminating character(s).

So you just take the line that is not terminated and print it out.

Source :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx